# django request transport to custom database backend

Tags: python, django, gssapi

My team is developing secure django project and we stacked with transport Django request into custom database backend.

We made such an algorithm for GSSAPI(SPNEGO) authentication in django and delegating user credentials for server querying on behalf of user:

```
    if 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' in request.META:
        kind, initial_client_token = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split(' ', 1)
        if kind == 'Negotiate':
            server = 'HTTP@server.domain.ru'
            _ignore_result, krb_context = kerberos.authGSSServerInit(server)
            kerberos.authGSSServerStep(krb_context, initial_client_token)
            principal = kerberos.authGSSServerUserName(krb_context)
            _ignore_result = kerberos.authGSSServerStoreDelegate(krb_context)
            conn = psycopg2.connect(
                host='krb5-dbhost',
                user=principal,
                dbname='db',
            )
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT version()")
            records = cursor.fetchall()
```

this works well in django-view. Kerberos server can authorize user and cache krb5-ticket for credentials delegation to query in psycopg. Now we need to inject it into django.

We want is inherit postgresql database backend like this:

```
from django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.base import DatabaseWrapper


class CustomDatabaseWrapper(DatabaseWrapper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_connection_params(self):
        '''We need to customize this function,
        We need get request here when query processed by web interface,'''
        #.... the source code could be here, but it is not necessary
        return conn_params
```

So the question is: "How can we get request.META (for get user`s Negotiate token) in get_connection_params() function, and how can we divide users request from web interface from management commands."

Sorry for my english skills.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

here is middleware and database backend, for cache used [django-lrucache-backend](https://github.com/kogan/django-lrucache-backend)

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.cache import caches
from django.conf import settings
import kerberos
import os


class GSSAPIMiddleware(object):
    """GSSAPI Middleware make user auth and cache user token
    and user name. Needed to fix gssstring response like
    spnego protocol says to return response with this string"""

    def process_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not settings.GSSAPI_ENABLED_OPTION:
            return None
        unauthorized = False
        if 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' in request.META:
            kind, initial_client_token = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split(' ', 1)
            if kind == 'Negotiate':
                local = caches['local']
                server = settings.GSSAPI_SERVER
                os.environ['KRB5_KTNAME'] = settings.GSSAPI_KEYTAB_PATH
                result, krb_context = kerberos.authGSSServerInit(server)
                kerberos.authGSSServerStep(krb_context, initial_client_token)
                # gssstring = kerberos.authGSSServerResponse(krb_context) FIXME
                principal = kerberos.authGSSServerUserName(krb_context)
                _ignore_result = kerberos.authGSSServerStoreDelegate(krb_context)
                local.set(settings.GSSAPI_USER_PRINCIPAL_KEY, principal)
            else:
                unauthorized = True
        else:
            unauthorized = True
        if unauthorized:
            return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)
        return None

    def process_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """function call for every view before Django
        choose witch view would be called. function
        ask user`s browser for Negotiate token"""
        if not settings.GSSAPI_ENABLED_OPTION:
            return None
        unauthorized = False
        if 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' in request.META:
            kind, initial_client_token = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split(' ', 1)
            if kind != 'Negotiate':
                unauthorized = True
        else:
            unauthorized = True
        if unauthorized:
            response = HttpResponse(request, status=401)
            response['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Negotiate'
            return response
        return None
```

and database backend for postgresql

```
from django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.base import DatabaseWrapper as DaWr
from django.core.cache import caches
from django.conf import settings


class DatabaseWrapper(DaWr):
    """Custom database backend version for GSSAPI auth
    get user creds from Kerberos and get ticket"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_connection_params(self):
        conn_params = super(DatabaseWrapper, self).get_connection_params()
        if settings.GSSAPI_ENABLED_OPTION:
            local = caches['local']
            principal = local.get(settings.GSSAPI_USER_PRINCIPAL_KEY)
            conn_params['user'] = principal
        return conn_params
```